# window.open popup not working in react native webview

Tags: react-native, uiwebview, android-webview

React Native webview is blocking window.open popup. How to enable them ?

adding
`@ReactProp(name = "javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically")
  public void setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(WebView view, boolean isCan){
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(isCan)
  }`

to `ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to document from React Native :
[Open Links and Deep Links (Universal Links)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

An example also illustrate how we can use useCallback to do so:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, Linking, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const supportedURL = "https://google.com";
const unsupportedURL = "slack://open?team=123456";
const OpenURLButton = ({ url, children }) => {
const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
// Checking if the link is supported for links with custom URL scheme.
const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

if (supported) {
  // Opening the link with some app, if the URL scheme is "http" the web link should be opened
  // by some browser in the mobile
  await Linking.openURL(url);
  } else {
  Alert.alert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`);
  }
}, [url]);

return <Button title={children} onPress={handlePress} />;
};

const App = () => {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <OpenURLButton url={supportedURL}>Open Supported URL</OpenURLButton>
      <OpenURLButton url={unsupportedURL}>Open Unsupported URL</OpenURLButton>
    </View>
 );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
});

export default App;
```